# 4 last characters truncated columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, truncated

I would like to :

1. Extract from df a movies DataFrame, containing only movies (movie content).
2. Create a new variable duree at movies, which contains the values of the duration variable with the last 4 characters truncated.
3. Change the type of the variable duration to int.

```
1. movies = df[df['type'] == 'Movie']
2. movies['duration'] = movies['duration'].astype(str).str[:-4]
3. movies['duration'].astype(int)
```

I can't create my new variable duree which contains the values of the duration variable with the last 4 characters truncated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a warning that occurs because the `movies` is a slice of your original df, so there is some ambiguity in pandas about which DataFrames should be modified because `movies` is directly derived from `df` - this is called `chained assignment`. Currently the way you have your code structured, pandas will modify the `movies` DataFrame without modifying `df` but this could lead to some unintended behaviors with more complex operations.

For your purposes, you can avoid chained assignment by setting movies to be a copy so it is not connected to df: `movies = df[df['type'] == 'Movie'].copy()`

If you are interested in a more in-depth discussion about chained assignment and why this warning occurs, there is already a great stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas).